# php artisan [BadMethodCallException]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

First of all I have just begun to tinker with Laravel 5 and php artisan, so don't judge to harsh please ;)

To get rid of `./public/index.php` in the website path I did the following:

1. moved all the files in `root/page_local/` folder;
2. moved files from public folder to `root/page/`;
3. modified the `root/page_local/index.php` file accordingly.

So the laravel works as it should now, but php-artisan is not. Every command that I try to run returns the same error:

```
[BadMethodCallException]
Method patter does not exist.
```

But I remember creating a Controller before and it worked, I tried multiple functions (--version, list, create::controller).
Even when I run `composer update` it errors when it tries to run `php artisan clear-compiled`. 
I still managed to update the composer by running `composer update --no-scripts`

Please help me out on this one because I couldn't find any information regarding this issue on Laravel website and google. If you will need me to provide any of my code, let me know what you need and I will do so.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why did you get rid of `./public/index.php` ?

Comment: I didn't get rid of the file itself. I wanted not having to type the whole path to access the page. For example type `localhost/sitename` in stead of `localhost/sitename/public`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search your code for **patter** string, my guess is that you have a typo somewhere and the method is called **pattern** so use that instead. There is no **patter** method anywhere in Laravel code.

Comment: OMG!!! Thanks a lot, it was a typo error in routes. I am not sure how artisan works though so I didn't knew that could be the issue. Do you, by any chance, know about any good source of information about how artisan works?